# writing custom protocol handler in Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, protocols

I want to write a `protocol handler` for an application in Chrome.
In Internet Explorer we can do this using `plug-gable protocol handler`.
Reference [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916%28VS.85%29.aspx), and in Firefox XPCOM utilities are available. I am not finding any way
in Chrome to achieve to this.

Comment: My application is running on local machine and need to re-parent its windows from standalone client to browser.

Comment: I found many references saying that chrome doesn't support it and use omnibox apis ins-ted. But they doesn't provide the mechanism similar to protocol.

Comment: Can I use code from chromium for this purpose. i.e. add a new feature to handle my own protocol. Googleurl package is present in chromium. Can I add extension to it.

Comment: I found many references on stack overflow and other sites but they all talk about protocol registration. I want to know about protocol handler.